# ArrayList to different class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java and I am trying to send the value of an ArrayList to another class in which I will display the value in a Text Field. So far I have

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] color= {"red", "blue"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for ( String x : joke )
      list.add(x);
    }
 }
```

And I have the second class

```
public class B extends JFrame{
  A a = new A();
  private JButton but;
  private JTextField txt;

  public B(){
    ...GUI declarations(layout, etc)
    but = new JButton("Button);
    txt = new JTextField(30);
    add(but);
    add(txt);
    ColorHandler color = new Color
    color.addActionListener(but);
  }

  private class ColorHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         txt.append(list.get(i).toString());
       }
     }
  }
```

I hope you understand my code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You never instantiate your gui.. you shouldn't put the main in `A` i think.

Comment: If you want `B` to use `list` you need to pass `list` to it in either a method or constructor (or it needs a reference to `A` and then it can call a method belonging to `A` to get the list

Comment: I try to pass it using a method but I have errors.

Comment: You shouldn't make a main method in `A` post a valid example demonstrating your issue learn more in [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is change your main method at the end by adding the following line:

```
new B(list);
```

and change the constructor of B to:

```
public B(ArrayList<String> list)
```

Then you'll have the values from your list in B as the variable named "list".

Moreover you should kick the following line from B since the Class containing the main method is your starting point, not vice versa.

```
A a = new A();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a B class with the list as parameter.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] color= {"red", "blue"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for ( String x : joke )
        list.add(x);
    }

    B class = new B(list);
}
```

Constructor with list parameter in class B

```
public B(List list){
    ...GUI declarations(layout, etc)
    but = new JButton("Button);
    txt = new JTextField(30);
    add(but);
    add(txt);
    ColorHandler color = new Color
    color.addActionListener(but);

    ArrayList array = list;
}
```